# API для мобильного приложения

Tags: api

Здравствуйте. У меня такой вопрос:
Я написал бэк веб-сайта с регистрацией и авторизацией. У меня теперь следующее задание: написать API для мобильного приложения.
Я пока не представляю с чего стоит начать. Могли бы вы посоветовать первые шаги или может быть годные статьи на эту тему? Заранее спасибо!